# Internationalisation of DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, date, internationalization

I am using joda DateTime for all the date and time manipulation in my web project. There is some scheduling and task specific implementation. I am trying to make this project internationalised by using `Locale`. Now the case is that I saw DateTime is printing as `2011-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30`, that DateTime object is created by `new DateTime()` (this is a part of aforesaid scheduling, I created a schedule where the date instance is created and saved by this way). I am testing from the same machine where I am developing the software. So if a user from France or Italy or USA access and use this website and create a schedule then what will be the representation of that date to them?

Will it be server-specific or client-specific (by client specific I mean If I set the Locale in the server as chosen by user, this is not related with javascript)?

Should I use Locale explicitly for this date instantiation? I can get that Locale easily. Then how can I use `Locale` for DateTime object creation or create `Date` or `Calendar` and then create `DateTime` by that `Date`?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

[DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is what you are looking for. You can localize the date to any locale.

It is best to use the locale of the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Costis Aivalis. Actually printing `2011-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30` means it is set to DateTimeZone IST. The `DateTime#toString()` method returns a DateTime instance in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` format. Where 'Z' represents the TimeZone. My question means If the server is situated in India then an user with timezone "America/Los_Angeles" will have there timezone set to IST, isn't it? Now I found a solution: by setting timezone explicitly by `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`.